# Javascript - Repeated if-statements don't work

Tags: javascript, random

My code works (doesn't fail), but it doesn't do the right thing.

I call the "generate" function every time i want to generate a new "chunk", passing a new number into the function each time its called. It generates the chunk fine, but it doesn't generate what I want it to generate.

I want it to generate either a space, a jump, a slide, or a gap, if the previous generation was a space. But if the previous generation wasn't a space, generate a space.
It doesn't do that. It sometimes generates 2 gaps, 2 jumps, or 2 slides after each other and i have no idea why... ???

Here is my code:

```
var ptg = 'space'; // what was previously generated to top
var wtgt; // what is currently being generated to top
var chunktogenerateto = 0;

function generate(a){
    chunktogenerateto = a;

    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + 1;

    if(ptg == 'space' && rand1 <= 25){
        wtgt = 'space';
    }
    else if(ptg == 'space' && rand1 <= 50 && rand1 > 25){
        wtgt = 'jump';
    }
    else if(ptg == 'space' && rand1 <= 75 && rand1 > 50){
        wtgt = 'slide';
    }
    else if(ptg == 'space' && rand1 > 75){
        wtgt = 'gap';
    }
    else{
        wtgt = 'space';
    }

    ptg = wtgt;

    topGen(wtgt);
}

function topGen(g){
    document.getElementById('t' + chunktogenerateto).setAttribute('src','images/terrain/t' + g + '.png');
}
```

I hope it's not a typo... HELP!

Where the calls to "generate" are coming from:

```
var chunkpos = new Array();
chunkpos[0] = -100;
chunkpos[1] = 0;
chunkpos[2] = 100;
chunkpos[3] = 200;
chunkpos[4] = 300;
chunkpos[5] = 400;
chunkpos[6] = 500;
chunkpos[7] = 600;
chunkpos[8] = 700;
chunkpos[9] = 800;
chunkpos[10] = 900;
chunkpos[11] = 1000;
var temppos = new Array();
var time1;
var millis1;
var time2;
var millis2;
var millis3;
var firstreset = true;
var pos;
var poschange;

function moveLevel(){
    if(firstreset == true){
        resetTime();
    }
    var time2 = new Date();
    var millis2 = time2.getTime();
    var millis3 = millis2 - millis1;
    poschange = Math.floor(millis3 / 5);
    for(i = 0; i < chunkpos.length; i++){
        temppos[i] = chunkpos[i] - poschange;
        if(temppos[i] <= -150){
            generate(i);
            temppos[i] += 1200;
        }
        pos = temppos[i];
        document.getElementById('chunk' + i).setAttribute('style','left: ' + pos + 'px;');
    }
}



function resetTime(){
    time1 = new Date();
    millis1 = time1.getTime();
    if(firstreset != true){
        for(i = 0; i < chunkpos.length; i++){
            chunkpos[i] = temppos[i];
        }
    }
    firstreset = false;
    setTimeout('resetTime()',1000);
}
```

Where the calls to "moveLevel" are coming from:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(test = 'runnable')
    {
        gameLoop();
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('gm').innerHTML = (gm + 'Failed to run game.');
    }
}

function gameLoop(){
    if(currentscreen == 'playing'){
        moveLevel();
    }
    setTimeout('gameLoop()',0);
}
```

Here is a download link to a zip file containing all of the code:
[ParkourFreak.zip](http://alpha-st.com/gabor/scripts/ParkourFreak.zip)
The code i'm having trouble with is under scripts/generation.js.
The main game page (where the generation is visible is index.html.

Comment: have u debig it? and cn u post full code?

Comment: @stay_hungry the syntax is correct and it is working, just not how i would like it to

Comment: My guess is the problem lies with you using global variables. `ptg` probably gets clobbered somewhere outside the code you posted. Try to get rid of globals and the spooky-action-at-a-distance: make `generate` a pure function with the previous image as a parameter, and the next image the return value. (I'd also get rid of making `rnd` an integer and the unnecessary greater-than comparisons but that's just me.)

Comment: Also, as some people who have answered already implied: Add `console.log(ptg)` at the start of your function, and `console.log(wtgt)` after the `if..else` block. If `ptg` is something else than what it should be after the previous call, you know what to look for.

Comment: @millimoose logging showed it's the same

Comment: You've said you're getting two gaps, or two slides, etc. I don't see the code doing that: http://jsbin.com/ogopuk  Two spaces, yes, but you said you meant to do that. My guess is it has to do with how you're calling `generate`, and in particular what you're passing into it as `a`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i don't know how its working for you. I'm using Google Chrome. Does that make a difference? Anyway i added a link to the entire code if you want to see it.

Comment: @kukac67: See the jsbin I posted above. If you can get that code to produce two non-spaces in a row, I'll be very surprised. Re the link: *Linking* full code is not sufficient for SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have no idea why its works for you and not for me, but ima try to copy your code... And i didnt post the entire code b/c i thought only this part was relevent, since i dont use the variables anywhere else. Thank you, though.

Comment: @kukac67: I hope it helps. The *calls* to `generate` are probably relevant.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added information that might be relevent.

Comment: @kukac67 So, when logging the values, you're getting a case when `ptgt` is not `'space'`, but `generate()` returns another not `'space'`?

Comment: Also: Why are you using global variables then SHADOWING them in some functions? This makes the code very very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the problem lied with the generation, when in fact all I had to do to solve it was to change this:

```
if(temppos[i] <= -100){
    generate(i);
    temppos[i] += 1200;
}
```

to this:

```
if(temppos[i] <= -100){
    generate(i);
    chunkpos[i] += 1200;
    temppos[i] += 1200;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than each if statement starting with "if(ptg == 'space' ... etc" - do this first in one simple "if not space return space".

After that you can start on your random - that should work for you.

Comment: i tried it. it still has the same problems as i mentioned in my question... It might be simpler, but it still managed to generate a gap right after a jump...

Answer (score 0):

Roughly a quarter of the time you previously had a space, it will create another, because of this code:

```
if(ptg == 'space' && rand1 <= 25){
    wtgt = 'space';
}
```

Note that it's creating a space when a space was previously created.

---

Side note:

There's no need for the `&& rand1 > 25` on this line:

```
else if(ptg == 'space' && rand1 <= 50 && rand1 > 25){
```

Since you previously had `if(ptg == 'space' && rand1 <= 25){`, it's impossible as of that line for `rand1` to be `<= 25` when `ptg == 'space'`.

(And similarly the `&& rand2 > 50` on the following condition.)

Comment: that isnt a problem though, i did that on purpose. read my question to see what my problem is...

Comment: If I read the question right, sequences of spaces are OK. Anything that's *not* a space has to be followed by at least one space though.

Comment: @kukac67: I thought the problem was two spaces in a row. I'm not seeing it ever create two non-spaces in a row: http://jsbin.com/ogopuk

Comment: @T.J.Crowder two spaces in a row is not a problem, the problem is when it generate 2 jumps in a row, or 2 slides, or a jump and a gap, etc.

Comment: @kukac67: Again: It doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it does for me :(

Comment: @kukac67: I'm afraid your question is incomplete, then. The code presented does not do that. My guess is it relates to the value you're passing into `generate` as the `a` argument, and the code is actually working correctly, but because you're using `a` to set `chunktogenerateto` and you're using `chunktogenerateto` to determine what element you act on, you're getting an unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're incrementing `chunktogenerateto`?

It appears to stay at 0 with the current code, is that in a segment you haven't shown?

Edit: oh, it's the argument of the function. Try logging that variable, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: im sure its incrementing because i am passing an incrementing argument into the function each time i call it. I KNOW that isnt the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
// elsewhere
var wtgts = ['space','jump','slide','gap'];

// in the function
if(ptg !== 'space') {
    wtgt = 'space';
} else {
    var randidx = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    wtgt = wtgts[randidx];
}
```

Or even in the function:

```
var newidx = (ptg == 'space') ? Math.floor(Math.random()*4) : 0;
wtgt = wtgts[newidx];
```

1. The weights were equal, so just pick a random index from 0 to 3 and use that to pick an action from an array.
2. Separate the logic for ptg being space so that you only test for it once
3. Consider denoting the actions as numbers instead of strings, as the assignment, comparison etc will be faster and more robust.

Comment: The OP's code posted isn't wrong in and of itself; a terser version won't fix his problem.